# opendir() of an ftp url fails

Tags: php, ftp

I'm trying to open a folder from a distant server. I wrote :

```
if ($folderHandle = opendir($folder))
```

where `$folder = "ftp://xxx:xxx@xxx.net:21"`

I get the weird error `Warning: opendir(ftp://...:21): failed to open dir: operation failed in ... on line 38`

Any ideas as to where I should go from here ? Is it a problem with the FTP credentials ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use PHP's [FTP Capabilities](http://php.net/ftp) to remotely connect to the server and get a directory listing:

```
// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect('otherserver.example.com'); 

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, 'username', 'password'); 

// check connection
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
    echo "FTP connection has failed!";
    exit; 
}

// upload the file
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY); 

// check upload status
if (!$upload) { 
    echo "FTP upload has failed!";
} else {
    echo "Uploaded $source_file to $ftp_server as $destination_file";
}

// Retrieve directory listing
$files = ftp_nlist($conn_id, '/remote_dir');

// close the FTP stream 
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Comment: ftp_connect connects fine (after a warning by the system's firewall), but I don't want to rewrite my whole script :(

Comment: @Manu - So then wait for other users if they come with alternative solution for you (if exists?!). I tried to help you as well and fast as I was able to... I am sorry it is not what you are looking for :-/

Comment: Your answer is just fine, and I will rewrite my script if I can't make opendir work as intended.